# Jekyll multisite with shared codebase?

Tags: jekyll

I am using Jekyll to build several websites. I want them to look and behave identically, just have different content. Thus, I'd like to be able to separate shared code (_includes, _layouts, etc.) from non-shared code (_docs and _data) and keep only one local copy and one repo of the shared code.

So far I have tried symlinks and [this plugin](https://stackoverflow.com). Symlinks create a lot of clutter and the plugin is just old and doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. So I guess neither solution is elegant.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.